# Open hyperlink ignoring current directory?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

We have a user submitted string that the user wants to be treated as a hyperlink when displayed on our site.

The users string will be displayed on the page like this:

```
<a href="userstring">userstring</a>
```

the issue this causes is that if the user enters *www.stackoverflow.com* they won't be redirected

Instead it would go to *http://mywebsite.com/www.stackoverflow.com*

So I'm looking for a way of a link being treated as absolute rather than relative via the html link tag?

otherwise I'm happy for any other suggestions. Maybe using javascript to open the link rather than html?

local file system and intranet links are the main issues at the moment with checking the string for http, www., https

we're currently using javascript and jquery, asp.net server side

Thanks in advance

Comment: You really need to reword this if you expect an answer. Maybe fill in a little more detail on how this form field becomes a hyperlink. Are you using javascript currently? Is a form submitted? Any languages used besides straight html?

Comment: I've made a few adjustments but I've left out how the user submits the string as my question is more about how the string get's displayed afterwards, thanks

Comment: What about appending `http://` before the string?

Comment: I think you want to add `http://` in front of the user input so it will become `<a href="http://userstring">userstring</a>`.

Comment: I considered appending http, the only issue with that is they'll need the ability to have links to local storage as well, the rule we're going with is we need anything that a user could succesfully type into an address bar

Comment: I think the best solution is to write your own filter and prepend `file://` or `http://` when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user submits a link, check whether it includes **http://, www, .com etc.** If it does not include, add it. Not only it will serve as a validation, it will make your links absolute.

As for ability to point to your own website (internal links) you can put extra radio buttons for internal or external links.

You can read about [absolute and relative URLs here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_href.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the response, my only concern with this is for the user submitting local file locations or intranet links?

Comment: I edited the answer. As I said, one simple solution is to ask user himself using radio button!

Comment: it's not quite how I'd like it to work but seems to be my only way of getting close, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify link protocol, host and optionally, port. Otherwise link will be considered as relative (to current context, i.e. to current protocol, host and port).

Check [location API](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) to see how you need to modifiy user's value before putting it into ***href*** attribute.

Comment: Looks promising! I'll take a look and get back to you soon, thanks

Comment: Helped me alot with understanding but the link doesn't contain anything that I could use to solve the answer. upvote for the knowledge though!